# Swift - Firebase how to get only childs values without parent

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the database i has a child cities with the name of "cities" under it and each city has multiple areas contains the coordinations

I went through every child under "cities" to find the closest location and got the city name using `ref.child("cities").observe()`:

```
for child in snapshot.children {

    let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot

    if let dicionary = childSnap.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

        var latitude1 = dicionary["latitude"] as! Double
        var longitude1 = dicionary["longitude"] as! Double
        var altitude1 = dicionary["altitude"] as! Double
```

lets say the closest city is "city 2" and place it in a variable called selectedCity.
So I repeat and add it to `ref.child("cities").child(selectedCity)`:

```
ref.child("cities").child("\(city2)").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

     if let dicionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

         print(dicionary)

         var altitude = dicionary["altitude"] as! Double
         var latitude = dicionary["latitude"] as! Double
         var longitude = dicionary["longitude"] as! Double
         var theCity = dicionary["cityName"] as! String

         if theCity == city2 {
             locationArray.add(location.init(area: area, city: theCity, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, altitude: altitude))
         }

     }

 })
```

Here is where i am getting the issue where im getting all the children under "cities" in "city 1" and "city 2" but skips the rest of the cities and then getting the children under "city 2" which is repeating the data

How can I get it to skip the parent "cities" and go to the child "city 2" and get the data once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a different way then what i was trying to do.

I placed all the data in a custom array - NSMutableArray()
then lopped through that array and added an if statement (city == city2) if it is true then the row is placed in a new array